# ng serve error: "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm new to Angular. I downloaded the Angular 2 quick-start template from https://github.com/angular/quickstart (app folder is inside an src folder), and then used VS code to modify packages.json content and manually create files/folders inside the app folder for components/services/etc.. based on tutorials that I found online. The application runs and works fine when I kick it off using `npm start` but I'm stuck creating the DIST folder which I need in order to upload a minified version of my application to azure web app. Whenever I run `ng build` from the root of my angular 2 project, I get the below error:

```
Cannot read property '0' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at Class.run (C:\AngularTestProject\node_modules\angular-cli\tasks\build-webpack.js:15:98)
at Class.run (C:\AngularTestProject\node_modules\angular-cli\commands\build.js:51:26)
at Class.<anonymous> (C:\AngularTestProject\node_modules\angular-cli\angular-cli\lib\models\command.js:152:17)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

This is the content of packages.json:

```
{
  "name": "EventRecorder",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
"angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.21",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

And lastly this is the folder structure of my app:
App Folder Structure
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Issue was resolved by installing the latest version of Angular CLI (1.0.0-rc.1) and recreating the Angular project (using `ng new projectname` command) and copying my TS files from my old project over.